# stop thread when task completed in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, concurrency

my code is :

```
if (save)
            {
                request.DataMessage = base.SaveChanges();
                if (request.DataMessage.IsSuccess)
                {
                    request.CustomID = arRequest.CustomID;                        
                    Task.Run(() => TaskWriteARAddLog(request, arTimestamp, arRequest, _tModel));

                }
            }
```

when single user works on my application ,than i am not getting any issue, but when multiple users are working than i am getting this issue :
"New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session."

Comment: This seems to be coming from EF/SQL, you should post TaskWriteARAddLog body. Maybe you're not disposing something.

Comment: yeah,it is coming from EF,, so please tell me solution ,

Comment: You are [using task.Run() for the wrong purpose](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html). For a suggestion we'd need to see the surrounding code.

Comment: i am using task.run() to create history,so there is not a issue, so tell me any alternate solution if you have or if you know any other alternate instead of task.run()...please asap...

Answer (score 0):

You can use lock statement to create a critical section so that block of code is executed by one thread at a time.

```
lock(_lockingObject)
{
                request.DataMessage = base.SaveChanges();
                if (request.DataMessage.IsSuccess)
                {
                    request.CustomID = arRequest.CustomID;                        
                    Task.Run(() => TaskWriteARAddLog(request, arTimestamp, arRequest, _tModel));

                }

}

//where _lockingObject is a field on your class:

object _lockingObject =new object();
```

[Here is a link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) where you can get some understanding of how lock statement works.

If you must use Task.Run(), the code should wait till the task is finished.

```
var task = Task.Run(...);
task.Wait();

// or 
Task.Run(...).Wait();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it will work fine, when i will use wait method here, but i don't want to use wait,because Task.Run() is creating history,it takes 20 secs.and i don't want to stop my frontend for 20 secs.this process will run in background.but without wait i am getting this error :" The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction." in my error log table,so tell me how can i fix it